# rfind() does not seem to work in Google Colab

Tags: google-colaboratory

The following code in Google Colab :

s = "12.3456"
l=len(s)
print(l)
s.find('.')
s.rfind('.')

has the outputs
7
2

It seems we cannot find the substring "." from the right using rfind() in Colab.
How can we count from the right then?

Answer (score 0):

Add `print` to print like so:

```
s = "12.3456"
l=len(s)
print(l)
print(s.find('.'))
print(s.rfind('.'))
```

By default, Colab outputs show what you 1) print explicitly and 2) a presentation of the value returned by the last statement.

So, executing a cell like:

```
'output'
```

is equivalent to

```
print('output')
```

But, if you write:

```
'output1'
'output2'
```

You'll only see `output2` if you don't prefix with `print` statements.

Comment: s.find('.')  gave the output value of  2,    
but s.rfind('.') had no output